# redux rejactjs Use one store for multiple actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, store

I am new in react and redux and I would like to know if it is possible to use one store for multiple actions.

I am trying this but the first action ges overwritten with the last action, why?

I am calling the action in two separate component and I call those two component in my app component.

reducer.js

```
const dataReducer = (state = {
  fetching: false,
  fetched: false,
  data: {},
  error: null
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_DATA_PENDING':
      return {...state, fetching: true}
      break;
    case 'FETCH_DATA_FULFILLED':
      return {...state, fetching: false, fetched: true, data: action.payload.data }
      break;
    case 'FETCH_DATA_REJECTED':
      return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload }
      break;
  }
  return state;
}

module.exports = dataReducer;
```

action.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const apiUrl = 'https://swapi.co/api/';

//fetch categories
export function fetchCategories() {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_DATA',
    payload: axios.get(apiUrl)
  }
}

//fetch films
export function fetchFilms() {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_DATA',
    payload: axios.get(apiUrl + 'films')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it this way, but the fact that both of your actions have the same type might be confusing in your reducers.  It might be more helpful to have a type `FETCH_FILMS` and `FETCH_CATEGORIES`.  That way the reducer can do separate things with them, unless of course, you *always* want *every* reducer to do the exact same thing with them.

Comment: I edit my post. i put with the reducer. My reducer do the same thing. that is why i want use one reducer.

Comment: Are you using a framework that sends the three fetch actions?  Because you currently are only sending `FETCH_DATA`. You are not sending `FETCH_DATA_PENDING` or the others listed in your reducer.